# maximum execution time for PHP

Tags: php

I am working to download images from a website and there comes an error saying `"Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"` and the downloading of images stopped. And I tried to add the following line of code that I thought could solve the problem:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //zero means forever I think, I also tried 200 or 300 seconds
```

And it didn't give me errors BUT the execution stopped (I mean the images stop downloading).

How can I make the execution time extend like 300 seconds? Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
function save_image($inPath,$outPath)
    { 
$in=    fopen($inPath, "rb");
$out=   fopen($outPath, "wb");
while ($chunk = fread($in,8192))
{
    fwrite($out, $chunk, 8192);
}
fclose($in);
fclose($out);
    }
```

And a method call:

```
foreach($li->find('a[class=thumbnail]') as $img) 
                    {
                        foreach($img->find('img') as $e)
                        {   
                            $image++;           
                           echo "<img src=\"" . $e->src . "\"/>" . "<br>";
                           save_image($e->src, 'thumbs/image'. $image .'.JPG');

                        }

                    }
```

That is the code that I'm using

Comment: There's probably a time limit on the functions you're using. Show us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could change the `max_execution_time` in your php.ini file so that it matches what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Make sure it's at the top of the document, just after `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `set_time_limit(0)` ([php.net](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)) instead.